# How to declare function return type `int (*)[3]`?

Tags: c

`int (*)[3] foo ();` doesn't work.

How to declare function return pointer to array of 3?

It might not be useful, but I want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Take a look [also Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37489236/function-returning-a-pointer-to-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I agree with the other answers that you probably need a `typedef` or a `struct` in there to clarify.

If you want to know how to **declare** the return type, it's
`int (*foo(void))[3] {`

In the ["declaration reflects use"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117024/why-was-the-c-syntax-for-arrays-pointers-and-functions-designed-this-way) pattern, you can build this up by considering the usage, i.e. how to get from `foo`'s type to the plain type `int`:

- take `foo`
- call it (with no arguments): `foo()`
- dereference the return value: `*foo()`
- add an array index: `(*foo())[i]`; the parentheses are needed because the postfix syntax would otherwise take precedence over prefix one.
- the result is of plain type `int`

Declaration reflects it:

- take `foo`
- call it: `foo(void)`, inserting `void` to say it's specifically a 0-param function rather than one with an unspecified set of parameters
- dereference the function return value: `*foo(void)`
- add an array index: `(*foo(void))[3]`, making the "index" be the size of the array
- we got down to the plain type, so declare that the thing you built has that type: `int (*foo(void))[3]`

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[3];
int (*foo(void))[3] {
  return &arr;
}
int main (void) {
  arr[0] = 413;
  arr[1] = 612;
  arr[2] = 1025;
  printf("%d %d %d\n", (*(foo()))[0], (*(foo()))[1], (*(foo()))[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Side note: be sure that the array you are returning a pointer to will continue to exist after the function returns.

Comment: IMHO this is a reasonable answer, but note that it is not  MISRA complant. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C

Comment: Yup. It's standard C. It's just a potential recipe for disaster. Just sayin'

Comment: @M.M Rebel ;-) But seriously, the OP should be aware of the potential flaws if they adopt this solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Also, could you please emphasize how you deduced the return type `int (*foo(void))[3] {` from what the OP asked `int (*)[3]`?  I did visit the link you posted, but couldn't comprehend this.

Comment: @Bathsheba Where did MISRA come from and what part of the code do you mean? MISRA doesn't say much about the use of array pointers at all. All it says is that array indexing `arr[i]` should be used in preference to pointer arithmetic `*(ptr+i)`. (Which was a stupid rule to begin with and I believe it's been phased out in MISRA 2012.)  `*foo()` is an array and `(*(foo()))[0]` is array indexing, so I actually don't think that part is a MISRA violation. It's a sanity violation, rather.

Comment: It's the `int arr[3];` at global scope that I have issue with.

Comment: Not being MISRA compliant isn't a flaw. If anything, it's a feature.

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise against doing this.

It's often done as a poor workaround for the apparent limitation that C has of not being able to have an array as a return value.

Too often, a *dangling* pointer will be returned since the programmer will return a pointer to an array in the function that has automatic storage duration. Then this gets hacked to a `static` which ruins the threading model and breaks all previous returned pointers!

Only slightly better is returning a pointer given to you by a `malloc` call internal to the function. But then, that burdens (asymmetrically) the caller with having to call `free` at some point. Eventually your function winds up in some kind of precompiled library which uses a different C runtime to a client. Your `malloc` and their `free` no longer match, and you end up with a truck load of undefined behaviour!

Instead of all this, do consider passing the array *by pointer* on the function parameter list, preferably pre-allocating the memory.

Comment: Your arguments would apply equally well to any function returning a pointer... this doesn't seem to have much to do with the question

Comment: My intention is to provide a "don't even think about doing it that way" kind of answer. But I like folk writing dodgy code. In 20 years I can come out of retirement when most folk only know PHP and Java, and charge loads of cash for C consultancy to pay for my Saga holidays.

Comment: Then obviously this should have been a _function pointer to a function returning an array pointer_. Even professional C programmers will struggle to read that, so you can charge even more :)

Answer (score 2):

One way is:

```
typedef int Int_array_3[3];

Int_array_3 * foo(void);
```

Comment: -1 This is a lazy poorly written answer with no explanation or substance that  exists only so the answerer can be the first to "answer" the question.

Comment: @MilesRout perhaps you could provide your own answer

Comment: @MilesRout Using a typedef is actually a pretty good idea, one which has substance -- though I agree that the answer should have more explanation.

Comment: By the way,I dont understand it..Could you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, avoid functions passing/returning raw array pointers or function pointers, because such code is a nightmare both to program and read. In this case it would have been

```
int (*func()) [3]
```

which is completely unreadable. Just forget about writing such code. Instead, use a typedef to define an array type:

```
typedef int iarr3_t [3];
```

And then write a function returning a pointer to such an array:

```
iarr3_t* func (void);
```

---

However, as indicated by other comments and answers, returning an array pointer is usually quite questionable practice to begin with. The need to do so could be an indication of poor program design.

Comment: It's only unreadable if you refuse to learn C. If you actually have any real familiarity with C, these types are very easy to understand.

Comment: @MilesRout Yes they are trivial, code like `int(*x(int(*)(int)))[3];` is very easy to read and C is sane and simple... right? **No**. If you have true experience of C, you'll call such code for what it really is: pure unreadable crap.

Comment: Incorrect, it's trivial to understand if you apply even a modicum of effort.

Comment: @MilesRout If it takes you longer than 5 minutes to understand a line of code, the code is truly awful. Now tell me what the code I just posted means, clock is ticking.

Comment: It's a function taking a pointer to another function and returning a pointer to an array of three integers. The argument function takes an int and returns an int. Didn't take me 4 mins to answer, it took me 4 mins to see you'd replied to me.